# Why does it take a shorter time to ping a website like google than a device on my wireless network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ping

I was trying to test the performance of my wireless network by pinging devices such as phones and laptops that are connected to it.

It turns out that I get very high pings (~100-200ms) when I try to ping my iphone and surface pro tablet. On the other hand, if I ping google.com, it is always around ~20ms. It doesn't seem to be the fault of the router as pinging the router gives me ~1ms.

How can a server that is kilometres away respond faster than a device that is sitting next to me?

Comment: What are your DNS settings? Are you using an external DNS such as OpenDNS or Google?

Answer (score 2):

Portables are terrible to test against, they save battery and scale down the connection. Ping an ipad thats "asleep" but wifi up, 400ms, wake ipad and stream video, 10ms.

Ping is no way to test wifi performance anyways.

Answer (score 0):

This is either the device taking its time to respond to an echo/ping request or a poorly optimised Wireless network.
If you have 2 wired devices, what are they like to ping each other and the wireless devices?